# sweetalet2 commonJS basic example

Tags: sweetalert2

I struggle to make a very simple commonJS usage:

`const Swal = require('sweetalert2');`

`Swal.fire('Hello world!');`

What's wrong with it?

if I run the code, nothing happens, no error it thrown either.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `require()` on browser/client-side JavaScript.

You need to grab SweetAlert2 from jsdelivr CDN by adding the following in your index.html

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
```

Then you can just run your JS

```js
Swal.fire('Hello world!');
```

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/ahandsel/pen/QWGrOya

Reference:
[Client on Node.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined/19059825#19059825)